# Как передать сообщение в канале телеграмма пользователю

Tags: php, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить сообщение ботом телеграмм в канал (бот добавлен - администратор)
но при тестовому запросу он выдаёт информацию для всех кто в канале.
Можно как-то сделать чтобы он отправил только тому кто дал команду, а для остальных было бы не видно результата запроса?

Запросы уходят через вебхук (php)
sendTelegram('sendDocument', array('chat_id' => $data['message']['from']['id'], 'document' => $row['file_id']));

вебхук видит это

```html
Array
(
    [update_id] => 488181322
    [message] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 13312
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1137877407
                    [is_bot] => 
                    [first_name] => User
                    [username] => wapstyle_ru
                    [language_code] => ru
                )

            [chat] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1137877407
                    [first_name] => User
                    [username] => wapstyle_ru
                    [type] => private
                )

            [date] => 1672926366
            [text] => /тест
        )

)
```

Comment: В массиве [from] есть id пользователя, по нему и отправляйте

Comment: Ну я вижу его, а команда тогда какая chat_id=$data['message']['from']['id'] такое не прокатывает
Улетает только так chat_id=$data['message']['chat']['id']